# When I ping one address in windows, it says another address was unreachable. Why?

Tags: windows-7, ip, ping

When I ping this address on my internal network, it says "reply from ....165". See below.

What does it mean? How is .165 relevant in this scenario?

```
Pinging 192.168.1.10 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.165: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.165: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.165: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.165: Destination host unreachable.
```

**edit**

Just realised the cable for .10 was sitting out of the router because the cable clip is broken. Pushed it back in and now when I ping it this is the result

C:\Users\Jason Fonseca>ping 192.168.1.10

```
Pinging 192.168.1.10 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
```

I'm still struggling to understand why it mentions .165 though.

Jason

Comment: I suggest getting a new cable, or putting a new terminator on the broken end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's also possible that `.165` is the address of your machine.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely your router (probably your default gateway) replying. You can check using `ipconfig`.

Answer (score 2):

`Reply from 192.168.1.165: Destination host unreachable.`

This doesn't mean .165 is not reachable but that .165 can't reach the address you asked to ping. Probably .165 is you own machine or your router.

Answer (score 1):

There are some switches (I've seen it from Netgear) that reply like that as well.  I don't believe this is correct behavior for the default gateway or switch.  It should report a time out